# How Can I use dual drive dedicated server as RAID1 array?

Tags: raid-1, webmin, dedicated-server

I am sort of newbie to linux, using hit & trial method to learn something new

Anyways I have just aquired dual drive (250GB each) Pre-Configured dedicated server which was installed using the install link provided in panel.

I have installed webmin/virtualmin to easyfy things

I want to use the 2 drives for RAID1

Below is the output of few commands I know

> [root@server ~]# df -h Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use%
>   Mounted on /dev/mapper/vg-root  225G   21G  193G  10% / tmpfs
>   1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm /dev/sda1            243M   39M  191M  17% /boot /dev/mapper/vg-tmp   976M  1.4M  924M   1% /tmp [root@server
>   ~]# mount /dev/mapper/vg-root on / type ext4
>   (rw,noatime,grpquota,discard,usrquota) proc on /proc type proc (rw)
>   sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw) devpts on /dev/pts type devpts
>   (rw,gid=5,mode=620) tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw) /dev/sda1 on
>   /boot type ext2 (rw) /dev/mapper/vg-tmp on /tmp type ext4
>   (rw,noatime,discard) none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc
>   (rw)

Comment: What are you asking? Have you checked if your motherboard supports RAID? If so, you are better to use this to set it up in your BIOS, so that it becomes transparent to any OS, including any external discs that you may need to boot.

Comment: Well this is a dedicated server not in physical access. I can only reboot it and install it thru a Contol Panel